# Storyboardで指定したフォントのウェイト(Style)が反映されない(iOS8のみ)

Tags: ios, ios8, storyboard

StoryboardでUILabelやUIButtonのフォントを指定してもiOS8のみフォントのウェイトが細くなってしまいます。iOS9では正しく設定されています。

StoryboardでのFont設定内容
・Font   - Custom
・Family - Hiragino Sans
・Style  - ヒラギノ角ゴシック W6
・Size   - 14

この設定でアプリを立ち上げるとiOS8のみ表示が"ヒラギノ角ゴシッック W3"となり細字になってしまいます。
コードで直接フォントを指定すれば反映されますがコードで指定したり、Storyboardで指定したりすると保守性に問題があるのでStoryboardで完結させたいです。

環境
OS 10.11.3(Capitan)
Xcode 7.2.1

どなたか対処方法ご存知でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

http://qiita.com/manji602/items/346226435594d36c2e9b

こちらの記事が参考になるかと思われますが、Xcode7(iOS9以上)のStoryboard上でHiragino Sansを指定した場合iOS8ではパフォーマンスが低下し描画がうまくいかないことが経験則として知られております。

そのため解決策としてはコードで指定されるといいかと思いますが、保守性の観点からそのようにはしたくないとのことですので、SystemFont Boldを採用されてはいかがでしょうか。SystemFontはヒラギノ角ゴとなっています。この場合、パフォーマンスも低下せずiOS8,9両方でBold指定ができるかと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
iOS8なんか遅いなーと思っていたらそういうことだったのですね。初めて知りました大変貴重な情報です。ありがとうございます。
また、SystemFontがヒラギノ角ゴ(Hiragino Sans)と知らずわざわざ今までHiragino Sansを設定していて無駄なことをしていたました。
一点疑問なのですが、SystemFontは昔から　ヒラギノ角ゴだったのでしょうか？もしSystemFontのフォントが今後の変更で全然違うフォントになってしまったら大変だと思ったので。

Comment: @penlight さん。英数字のシステムフォントについてはiOS9からHelveticaからSan Franciscoへの変更が行われたばかりですので、日本語のSystem Fontであるヒラギノ角ゴについても後々変更が行われる可能性もあるかもしれません。また、SystemFontの歴史についてはあまり詳しくなく申し訳ありませんが、今現在サポートすべきiOSのバージョンでは、日本語のSystemFontについてはヒラギノ角ゴであると考えていいと思われます。